# Is there a possibility for concurrency issues when calling a method of class from a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

```
public class ThreadTest {
   private final ListeningExecutorService executor;

public ThreadTest() {
   this.executor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
}

public void processAsync() {
 int i=0;
 do {
    final Future<Integer> future = processThread(i));
    futures.add(future);
    i++;
 } while (i<10);
 int count = 0;
    for (Future<Integer> f : futures) {
        try {
            count+=f.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error occurred", e);
        }
    }
}


private Integer updateCount(Integer i) {
    Integer a = Math(i,2);
    a = a + 20;
    Integer b = a + 40;
    return b;
}


public ListenableFuture<Integer> processThread(Integer i) {

    return this.executor.submit(()->{
        return updateCount(i);
    });
}
```

In this small snippet of code, would I need to synchronize anything in the `updateCount()` method if I called the `processAsync()` method of the class? Would multiple threads invoking `updateCount()` result in the temporary variables being `created(i, a , b)` to be out of synch and return garbage values?

Comment: You only have thread safety concerns when you're modifying a mutual state across multiple threads. As your code does **not** have a shared state it is effectively thread safe

Comment: Just a side note: You said, "...calling a method...from a thread," as if there was some other place from which a method could be called. But in fact, there is no such other place. Everything your program does happens in a thread. In the world of multi-threaded programming, "thread" is the name for the thing that executes your code.